# C: control reaches end of non void function... Even though it returns int?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver

I"m writing a character device in C (for linux). I have this function:

```
static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *file,
     const char __user * buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset)
{
    int i, fd = 0;
    int = bytes_written;

    fd = open(file, O_WRONLY);

    printk("device_write(%p,%d)\n", file, length);

    for (i = 0; i < length && i < BUF_LEN-1; i++)
        get_user(Message[i], buffer + i);

    bytes_written = write(fd,Message,i);
    Message[BUF_LEN-1] = '\0';
    /* return the number of input characters used */
    return bytes_written;
}
```

And when I compile I get error: control reaches end of non-void function. I've double checked that I'm compiling the right program, and it's driving me nuts.

Any help would be welcome.

Also, slightly unrelated, but is it possible to init a char buffer to a certain string (e.g. char `buffer[1000] = "HELLO"`)?

Comment: This function has many errors.

Comment: For a start: you return a signed int from an unsigned function. use the same type!

Comment: Yes, you can initialize a char array with a string literal. All elements not individually initialized get a `'\0'` ... so after `char buffer[1000] = "HELLO";` all elements from `buffer[5]` to `buffer[999]` (inclusive) have that `'\0'`

Comment: Yes @Olaf, I am sure. In C there is no such thing as *"partial initialization"*. See [6.7.9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21 "If there are [...] fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration. "

Comment: @pmg: Found myself already. Thanks!

Comment: what is this line: 'int = bytes_written;' expected to do?   I can tell you it does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has many problems

1. This is invalid

   ```
   int = bytes_written;
   ```

   Maybe you mean

   ```
   int bytes_written;
   ```
2. You must check `fd != -1`, any code following `open()` will "*potentially*" cause a *Invalid file descriptor* error, because you have no guarantee that `fd` is a valid descriptor.

   And you can't even know whether the error was set or not, because

   1. You don't check whether `write()` succeeded.
   2. You don't check what is the value of `errno` after every call that can possible set it's value `!= 0`, namely `open()` and `write()`.
3. This `Message[BUF_LEN-1] = '\0';` is very likely wrong, it would be `Message[i - 1] = '\0'`;

   And it seems logical to do

   ```
   memcpy(Message, buffer, length); 
   Message[length] = '\0';
   ```
4. As commented by @[zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169065/c-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-even-though-it-returns-int/31169139#comment50346180_31169139), you can't use `open()` or `write()` from kernel space.

Comment: 4) `open` and `write` can't be used directly from kernel space AFAIK 5) `fd` is never closed

Comment: @zwol I don't know that, But I am adding it anyway.

Comment: Add to this happily mixing signed and unsigned and different types (ssize_t, size_t, etc). This is getting more like a code review.

Answer (score 0):

`int = bytes_written;` shoud be `int bytes_written;` at least to fix your current error.  There are likely others.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Would have been better a comment.

Comment: Actually, from appearances it should be `ssize_t bytes_written;`